# R: pnorm with lower.tail = T and lower.tail = F give same value

Tags: r

I don't understand why the pnorm `lower.tail = F` and `lower.tail = T` give me the same value:

```
> val
[1] 5100000
> mean
[1] 5e+06
> sd
[1] 40000
> pnorm(val,mean,sd,lower.tail=F)
[1] 0.9937903
> pnorm(val,mean,sd,lower.tail = T)
[1] 0.9937903
> 1 - pnorm(val,mean,sd,lower.tail=F)
[1] 0.006209665
>
```

I would expect the `1 - pnorm(val,mean,sd,lower.tail=F)` to be the same as `lower.tail = T`. And why does `lower.tail = T` and `lower.tail = F` return the same value... Probably I'm just missing something

**UPDATE**
I just restarted R studio and the problem seems to be solved now. But the most interesting is what could have caused this?

Comment: what is your value of `F`?  I can reproduce it when I do `F <- TRUE; pnorm(val, mean, sd, lower.tail = F)`.  What do you get when using `lower.tail = FALSE`?

Comment: `pnorm(val,mean,sd,lower.tail=F)` gives `0.006209665`

Comment: So there should have been a variabele (F or T) which I have gave a value?

Comment: Yes.  And I'm guessing it was `F` that had the value assigned.  This is the reason I never use `F` or `T` as logical values.  I recommend always using the full `FALSE` and `TRUE`.

Comment: thankyou great advise hahah can you answer this question so I can check it as a good answer maybe this will help out some people @Benjamin